# How to integrate the following floor function?

Tags: integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to calculate the following integral,
$$\int_{1}^{10}\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor }{x^2} dx$$.

So I did this-

$$\int_{1}^{10}\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor }{x^2} dx=\int_{1}^{10}\frac{1 }{x} dx-\int_{1}^{10}\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2}dx.$$ Now my problem is with the second integral. How can I calculate this? I have tried to looking for examples here but in all those example there only the floor function is involved not a denominator part as I have. So how can I do this? Please help.

Comment: Cut it into 9 integrals: $\int_1^2+\int_2^3+\ldots+\int_9^{10}$

Comment: Why I need to do that? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: For $x\in[1,2)$, $\lfloor x\rfloor=1$.

Comment: Over each of the nine intervals, the floor function reduces to a constant term. i.e. $\int_1^2\lfloor x\rfloor /x^2~dx=\int_1^21/x^2~dx$, $\int_2^3\lfloor x\rfloor /x^2~dx=\int_2^32/x^2~dx$, $\int_3^4\lfloor x\rfloor /x^2~dx=\int_3^43/x^2~dx$, etc.

Comment: ok got it @NathanielB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute integrals of the form $\displaystyle \int_n^{n+1} \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2} dx$.
You get

\begin{align}
    \int_n^{n+1} \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2} dx
    &= \int_n^{n+1} \dfrac{n}{x^2} dx \\
    &= \left. \dfrac{-n}{x} \right|_n^{n+1}\\
    &= \dfrac{-n}{n+1} + 1\\
    &= \dfrac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}

Then

$\displaystyle \int_1^{10} \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2}dx
= \int_1^2 \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2}dx +
\int_2^3 \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2}dx + \cdots +
\int_9^{10} \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^2}dx$

and so on.

Comment: I got $\int_n^{n+1} \dfrac{n}{x^2} dx= \dfrac{1}{n+1}$. Can you double check the factor "2"?

Comment: @mike - got it.